# Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'XMLFOREST'

Tags: php, mysql, xml, mysqli

I'm following a tutorial and am using PHP to retrieve data from a MySQL database.

I'm passing the following query found on this [page](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlxml-sqlx-generating-xml-content-using-sql.php):

```
$query="SELECT XMLROOT(
         XMLELEMENT('RATINGS',
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT('RATING',
               XMLFOREST(
                 ratingid AS 'ID',
                 rating AS 'RATING',
                 comment AS 'COMMENT')
             )
           )
         )
       ) AS RATINGS
  FROM ratings
 WHERE ratingforid=?";

$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
($stmt->prepare($query))|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL prepare', $db->error);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$username)|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
$stmt->execute()|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL execute', $db->error);
```

But I get the error: Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'XMLFOREST'? I can't figure out which parameters are incorrect.

Comment: @rid I'm actually not sure what you're asking me, sorry, this PHP & SQL is new to me, so I'm trying to get an XML output from a query on a database. I found this webpage: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlxml-sqlx-generating-xml-content-using-sql.php

Comment: You mean the function XMLFOREST? I was assuming I could just call that function.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: @CL,SQLite, so it might have something to do with that

Comment: Why do think you're using SQLite? That error message can only be returned by MySQL.

Comment: I'm opening the database like this $db = new mysqli(... that's why I think it's SQLite.

Comment: "mysqli" stands for "MySQL" and "interface".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an XML output from database you have to get your data and wrap it in XML tags, **exactly the same way** as it shown in any PHP/Mysql tutorial, save for there are HTML tags are used.

While no Oracle functions can be used in Mysql, and you need no SQL function at all.

Comment: I used your method in the end, but I like the approach as mentioned above, is that not possible?

Comment: I have no idea. you have to have an Oracle database in the first place. Do you?